# Where does this recursion formula come from?

Tags: proof-explanation, recurrence-relations, solution-verification, recursion

I come across an explanation of recursion complexity.  This screenshot is in question:

[image: a]

How do you get this?

```
T(n) = 3T(n/4) + n
```

The $log_n^4$ shown seems to be base 4, and this baffles me.  What does the `n` superscript stand for?  I am inclined to think the base of this log should be 3.  Can someone explain this to me?

---

Another example was provided where the tree expands at an exponent of 2:
[image: b]

The formula given is:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 2
```

The `log(n)` given is said to be of base 2.  This makes sense to me, but not the base 4 in given by the first picture.

Comment: I am inclined to think that they were supposed to be $\log_4n$ and $3^{\log_4n}$.

Comment: @Gae.S., how can it be base 4 when the tree expands at an exponent of 3?

Comment: Sorry, what?${}$

Comment: The formula $T(n)=3T(n/4)+1$ doesn't come from the tree. The tree is a visualization of the formula. The formula describes the amount of work done by a recursive algorithm, and the numbers written at the nodes of the tree represent work done in specific parts of the algorithm's execution.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
T(n)
&=3T(n/4)+1\\
&=3(3T(n/16)+1)+1\\
&=9T(n/16)+4\\
&=9(3T(n/64)+1)+4\\
&=27T(n/64)+13\\
&.....\\
&=3^kT(n/4^k)+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}3^j
\qquad\text{conjecture}\\
&=3^k(3T(n/4^{k+1})+1)+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}3^j
\qquad\text{induction step}\\
&=3^{k+1}T(n/4^{k+1})+3^k+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}3^j\\
&=3^{k+1}T(n/4^{k+1})+\sum_{j=0}^{k}3^j
\qquad\text{confirmed}\\
\end{array}
$

Note that the induction stops when
$4^k \ge n$.

Also note that
$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}3^j
=\dfrac{3^k-1}{3-1}
=\dfrac{3^k-1}{2}
$.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, we're considering an algorithm that, given a problem of size $n$, does 1 unit of "local" work and divides the remaining work into 3 smaller problems of the same kind, where each of these subproblems has size $n/4$. (Instead of 3 and 4 we could have any numbers; this is just an example.) So if $T(n)$ is the total amount of work done in solving a problem of size $n$, we have the equation $T(n)=3T(n/4)+1$ by assumption.

The tree figure shows a way of thinking about the algorithm and understanding the growth rate of $T$. At $k$ levels below the root, we have $3^k$ subproblems and each subproblem has size $n/4^k$. Since our algorithm stops splitting the problem up when it reaches a base case (i.e. a problem of size 1), the tree has $\log_4n$ levels, and the number of base cases at the bottom level is $3^{\log_4n}$.

Comment: Can you explain to me what is `n` at each level of that tree?

Comment: If you're referring to the second picture, each of the $n$'s on the side is the sum of the numbers in that row, i.e. the amount of work done by the algorithm at that level of recursion. This is an algorithm like MergeSort, which recursively sorts two halves of the input list (which takes $2T(n/2)$ time) and then merges the results together (which takes $n$ time), which is why we have $T(n)=2T(n/2)+n$.

Comment: It's hard to think of a real algorithm that makes 3 recursive calls on subproblems of size $n/4$ (and only does O(1) additional work per call), but we can still analyze the runtime of such an algorithm.

Comment: I was referring to the first picture.  I cant come up with an explanation what `n` is at each level.  I am not sure if `n` is that 1, 3, 9 sequence or how it fits into the given formula.

Comment: In the diagrams, $n$ is a fixed number and we're trying to figure out how large $T(n)$ is. The 1,3,9 are the sums of the 1s in each row. $T(n)$ is the sum of all these numbers. These slides are missing a lot of words, so they won't make sense if you don't know what they're about. Do you understand how a computer executes a recursive algorithm?

Comment: I do understand recursion in CS.  Just trying to make sense of this poorly made slide.  Say if $T(3)$ is the sum of all operations at level 3 (n = 3, 2 levels of recursion), then what exactly is T(3/4) when you plug it in?

Comment: You should think of $n$ as a very large number. In practice, a recursive algorithm will round the division (e.g. you'll split a list of length 7 into a pair of lists of sizes 3 and 4 for the recursive calls), but the rounding doesn't affect the analysis. For small input sizes, the algorithm quickly reaches a base case, so the amount of work done is a small constant; we can assume $T(3/4)=T(1)=1$.